# Make filter in lightning:listView

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using [lightning:listView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation).

I want to use filter like standard listView, but it's not in support.

I could find just [custom list view changer](https://sfdcmonkey.com/2019/02/03/dynamic-list-view-salesforce-lightning/), but there was no filter.

Can I make custom filter in this way?

(I mean how can I make custom component which can do what I want to do.)

Image from [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-for-salesforce-classic-users/work-with-list-views)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with the out of the box lightning:listView, you would have to create a custom component that does that

Comment: how can I create such a custom component?
there is no info about how to affect listview from other components.